# Salesforce Soql query is limited to first 150 rows in custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I am confused as to why a SOQL query against a custom object is only returning the first 150 rows when it should be returning up to the governor limit (50,000). Does anyone have any ideas why my query is being limited?

Here's my controller method:

```
@RemoteAction
public static List<Metro__c> getAllMetros(){
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, state__c FROM Metro__c ORDER BY Name';
    List<Metro__c> r = Database.query(query);
    System.debug('r='+r.size());
    return r;
}
```

When i look at the debug I see:

```
10:48:27:237 USER_DEBUG [54]|DEBUG|r=150
```

There are several thousand records in the Metro__c object. Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: It should not happen. Looks odd.

Comment: How many of the Metro records can the user calling the remote method access?

Comment: I can  see all of the records when I look at the data in the object (via a custom tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my issue.  The problem was how i was getting data into the Metro Object.  I was reaching the 150 SoQL queries per request limit and I did not realize all of the records were not present in the object.  After changing how the records were inserted, it all works properly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have a batch size of 150. You can set this by

```
connection.setQueryOptions(250);
```

when you execute query() function you'll get 250 records and you need to use queryMore() to continue catching the next batches.

Please check the Salesforce documentation:
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query.htm

and

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm